# Ubuntu command to constantly monitor a service?

Tags: ubuntu, grep, command-line-interface

I was curious if anyone new a command like tail or top to constantly 
monitor a service as it runs. I'm trying to watch sendmail currently
to see who is connecting to it, but would like to have it a little
more dynamic than just repeatedly typing ps aux | grep send

is there a good way to constantly keep this running? Thanks guys n' gals

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/mail.log | fgrep send`

Comment: Awesome I didn't think about just tailing the file. Thanks mailq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `watch` command along with `ps -aux` to refresh. `watch -n 5 "ps -axf |grep send"` will run the `ps` command every 5 seconds (note the quotes).

Comment: Great this is the answer, just waiting for the four minutes to chalk down to accept. Thanks slillibri (sp?)

Comment: I have an alternative use for watch, which is the nastiest hackiest continuous integration ever.  `watch git pull`